# How to select best Machine Learning model for unbalanced dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a problem statement in which I am trying to predict the occurrence of an event i.e if occurs labeled as 1 and if not occurs labeled as 0 at a time instant. Consider I have a data set in which event occurs at a time instant 't' the time 't' on which event occurs is calculated as (day of the week + hour of the day). I have huge data set in which most of the time instants have 0 values and ceratin has 1 value more precisely they are in the ratio of 8:2.
The data set is as:

[image]

I have tried certain scikit models such as **Logistic Regression** and the **Bayesian model**. I also balanced the weights of classes but doesn't get the expected result. It either produces all 0 due to heavyweight or on balancing (using scikit sampling) it will always predict 1 if my existing input is t->[0,0,1,0].

If anyone has any idea kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the following example which shows different strategies to correct the bias induced by the class imbalanced problem:

https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_impact_imbalanced_classes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-impact-imbalanced-classes-py

Basically, you can either `resample`, combine it to learn an `ensemble` or change the weight of the model (as apparently your already did). You need to choose a good metric which is not affected by the balancing as the `balanced_accuracy_score`, `precision`, `recall`. You can given a look at the [classification report](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/generated/imblearn.metrics.classification_report_imbalanced.html#imblearn.metrics.classification_report_imbalanced) from imbalanced-learn which summarize these metrics.